# LoopBack consume CPU & Memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb, loopback

I'm using Loopback + NodeJS for my mobile backend system.

Currently I'm testing in UAT environment with Server Spec (VM):

- 2 Core (CPU)
- 1.995 CPU MHz
- 4 GB Memory

I have 2 UAT MongoDB (separate server with Loopback) with each statistic:

---

```
{ 
    "db" : "A", 
    "collections" : NumberInt(35), 
    "views" : NumberInt(0), 
    "objects" : NumberInt(59018291), 
    "avgObjSize" : 254.90223315683608, 
    "dataSize" : 15043894173.0, 
    "storageSize" : 4575064064.0, 
    "numExtents" : NumberInt(0), 
    "indexes" : NumberInt(59), 
    "indexSize" : 1891119104.0, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}

{ 
    "db" : "B", 
    "collections" : NumberInt(33), 
    "views" : NumberInt(0), 
    "objects" : NumberInt(316693), 
    "avgObjSize" : 216.2786042002823, 
    "dataSize" : 68493920.0, 
    "storageSize" : 21401600.0, 
    "numExtents" : NumberInt(0), 
    "indexes" : NumberInt(34), 
    "indexSize" : 3956736.0, 
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

---

When I use DB "B", CPU usage on Loopback is 0% with no request.
When I change to DB "A", CPU usage on Loopback is 50% with no request (99% on NodeJS / Loopback process)

---

```
top - 05:42:12 up 19:59,  4 users,  load average: 0.58, 0.64, 0.61
Tasks: 137 total,   2 running, 135 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 47.0 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 50.2 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   4056212 total,   999168 used,  3057044 free,      876 buffers
KiB Swap:   561148 total,        0 used,   561148 free.   323368 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND

 5068 root      20   0 1426748 341212  11784 R 97.33 8.412   8:27.13 node /hom+

-----
```

99% without any request on that loopback server. Is that normal?
Because when I see MongoDB log there is no log process & there is no CPU & Memory consumable on MongoDB.

Comment: Oke, I'll try. Thanks partycoder.

Comment: Hi partycoder, I try to install the package, but it seems error, is there any other source to install?

Comment: Ok, thank you partycoder. I will read it first.

Comment: Hi partycoder, thanks for your input, I've already identified the slow queries process. Thanks.